# Find up-to-date files for different paths but with identical file names

Tags: perl, bash, find

I have the following files

```
./path/to/stuff1/file1    (x)
./path/to/stuff1/file2
./path/to/stuff1/file3

./path/to/stuff2/file1
./path/to/stuff2/file2    (x)
./path/to/stuff2/file3

./path/to/stuff3/file1    (x)
./path/to/stuff3/file2
./path/to/stuff3/file3
```

where I marked the files I touched lastly. I want to get exactly those marked files. In other words:

- I want to get the up-to-date **file** for each directory.

I constructed the bash command

```
for line in $( find . -name 'file*' -type f | awk -F/ 'sub($NF,x)' | sort | uniq ); do
        find $line -name 'file*' -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d' '
done
```

which I am able to use in perl using the `system` command and escaping the `$`. Is it possible to do this directly in perl or do you think my approach is fine?

**edit**

If possible the task should be done in perl without using external modules.

**edit2**

Sorry, I noticed my question wasn't clear. I thought the answer of @TLP would work but I have to clearify: I want to check for the newest file in each folder, e.g. the newest **file** in **stuff1**. Say I do

```
touch ./path/to/stuff1/file1
touch ./path/to/stuff2/file2
touch ./path/to/stuff3/file1
```

before I run the script. It then should output:

```
./path/to/stuff1/file1
./path/to/stuff2/file2
./path/to/stuff3/file1
```

The filename can be identical for different **stuff** but only one file per path should be output.

The script of @codnodder does this but I wish to search for only for the filename and not for the full path. So I want to search for all files beginning with **file** and the script should search recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `find` command can be emulated with `File::Find`'s `find` command. This is a core module in Perl 5, and is almost certainly already on your system. To check the file modification time, you can use the `-M` file test.

So something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my %times;
find(\&wanted, '.');
for my $dir (keys %times) {
    print $times{$dir}{file}, "\n";
}

sub wanted {
    return unless (-f && /^file/);
    my $mod = -M $_;
    if (!defined($times{$File::Find::dir}) or
        $mod < $times{$File::Find::dir}{mod}) {
        $times{$File::Find::dir}{mod} = $mod;
        $times{$File::Find::dir}{file} = $File::Find::name;
    }
}
```

If I run this command in my test directory, on my system, I get the following `Data::Dumper` structure, where you can clearly see the file name key, the full path stored in the `file` key, and the modification date (in days compared to the run time of the script) as the `mod`.

```
$VAR1 = {
          './phone' => {
                         'file' => './phone/file.txt',
                         'mod' => '3.47222222222222e-005'
                       },
          './foo' => {
                       'file' => './foo/fileb.txt',
                       'mod' => '0.185'
                     },
          '.' => {
                   'file' => './file.conf',
                   'mod' => '0.154490740740741'
                 }
        };
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I just noticed your script isn't outputting the expected files. I edited the question...

Comment: That's just a matter of changing the key to directory name instead.. which I've done now.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 general approaches I can think of.

1. Using opendir(), readdir(), and stat().
2. using File::Find.
3. Using glob().

The most appropriate option depends on the specifics of what you have
to work with, that we can't see from your posting.

Also, I assume when you say "no external modules", you are not
excluding modules installed with Perl (i.e., in Core).

Here is an example using glob():

```
use File::Basename qw/fileparse/;

for my $file (newest_file()) {
    print "$file\n";
}

sub newest_file {
    my %files;
    for my $file (glob('./path/stuff*/file*')) {
        my ($name, $path, $suffix) = fileparse($file);
        my $mtime = (stat($file))[9];
        if (!exists $files{$path} || $mtime > $files{$path}[0]) {
            $files{$path} = [$mtime, $name];
        }
    }
    return map { $files{$_}[1] } keys %files;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention that I am using Perl 5.10.1. And yes, it's no problem to use core modules.

Comment: Your script also works. I changed one line to `$files{$path} = [$mtime, "$path$name"];` which got me the desired output of the file path. Would like to accept both answers, thx guys.