# Issues with function calls for search routine

Tags: perl, function, find

My aim is to have multiple searches of specific files recursively. So I have these files:

```
/dir/here/tmp1/recursive/foo2013.log
/dir/here/tmp1/recursive/foo2014.log
/dir/here/tmp2/recursive/foo2013.log
/dir/here/tmp2/recursive/foo2014.log
```

where the 2013 and 2014 says in which year the files got modified lastly.

I then want to find the more up to date files (`foo2014.log`) for each directory tree (`tmp1` and `tmp2` likewise).

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20542968/2622293) I have the following code in **script.pl**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

func("tmp1");
print "===\n";
func("tmp2");

sub func{
    my $varName = shift;
    my %times;
    find(\&upToDateFiles, "/dir/here");

    for my $dir (keys %times) {
        if ($times{$dir}{file} =~ m{$varName}){
            print $times{$dir}{file}, "\n";
            # do stuff here
        }
    }

    sub upToDateFiles {
        return unless (-f && /^foo/);
        my $mod = -M $_;
        if (!defined($times{$File::Find::dir})
         or $mod < $times{$File::Find::dir}{mod})
        {
            $times{$File::Find::dir}{mod} = $mod;
            $times{$File::Find::dir}{file} = $File::Find::name;
        }
    }
}
```

which will give me this output:

```
Variable "%times" will not stay shared at ./script.pl line 25.
/dir/here/tmp1/recursive/foo2014.log
===
```

I have three questions:

1. Why isn't the second call of the function `func` working like the first one? Variables are just defined in the scope of the function so why am I getting interferences?
2. Why do I get the notification for variable `%times` and how can I get rid of it?
3. If I define the function `upToDateFiles` outside of `func` I am getting this error: `Execution of ./script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.` I think this is because the variables aren't defined outside of `func`. Is it possible to change this and still get the desired output?

Comment: You could instead of `sub upToDateFiles { ...` use `my $upToDateFiles = sub { ...`, define before the find call, and use it as `find($upToDateFiles, ...`.

Comment: @Qtax Thx, this works like a charm! I would be pleased if you could elaborate/explain a bit and propose an answer. I could also upvote then :)

Answer (score 3):

For starters - embedding a sub within another sub is rather nasty. If you `use diagnostics;` you'll get:

```
(W closure) An inner (nested) named subroutine is referencing a
lexical variable defined in an outer named subroutine.

When the inner subroutine is called, it will see the value of
the outer subroutine's variable as it was before and during the *first*
call to the outer subroutine; in this case, after the first call to the
outer subroutine is complete, the inner and outer subroutines will no
longer share a common value for the variable.  In other words, the
variable will no longer be shared.

This problem can usually be solved by making the inner subroutine
anonymous, using the sub {} syntax.  When inner anonymous subs that
reference variables in outer subroutines are created, they
are automatically rebound to the current values of such variables.
```

Which is directly relevant to the problem you're having. Try to avoid nesting your subs, and you won't have this problem.  It certainly looks like you're trying to be far more complicated than you need to. Have you considered something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use File::Find;

my %filenames;

sub compare_tree {
    return unless -f && m/^foo/;

    my $mtime = -M $File::Find::name;

    if ( !$filenames{$_} || $mtime < $filenames{$_}{mtime} ) {
        $filenames{$_} = {
            newest => $File::Find::name,
            mtime  => $mtime,
        };
    }
}

find( \&compare_tree, "/dir/here" );

foreach my $filename ( keys %filenames ) {
    print "$filename has newest version path of:", $filenames{$filename}{newest}, "\n";
    print "$filename has newest mtime of:",        $filenames{$filename}{mtime},  "\n";
}
```

I'd also note - you seem to be using `$File::Find::dir` - this looks wrong to me, based on what you describe you're doing. Likewise - you're running `find` twice on the same directory structure, which is not a very efficient approach - very big finds are expensive operations, so doubling the work needed isn't good.

Edit: Caught out by forgetting that `-M` was:  `-M  Script start time minus file modification time, in days.`. So 'newer' files are the lower number, not the higher. (So have amended above accordingly).

Comment: This isn't working. It gives an warning plus the output isn't the desired one.

Comment: The hint with avoiding nested subs is good. I asked for it in point 3). Still I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: Aborted due to compliation errors it the error you get _after_ it's given you other warnings. Turn on `use diagnostics` and see what it says.

Comment: I just copied your code (with diagnostics) and tried it... it's not running correctly because mtime is undefined and the output "newest" file isn't actually the newest. Is this code working for you?

Comment: Got muddled about the '-M'. I thought that was the mtime, but it's not: `  -M  Script start time minus file modification time, in days.` So switch the direction of the arrow (edited in code). Otherwise - no errors when I run it, and it correctly identifies the newer 'foo2014.log' within my faked up directory structure.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting undefined mtime though. Any chance one of those files is unreadable?

Comment: You could also solve your issues identified in 2) and 3) by wrapping the find handler in a closure, then calling the handler with any necessary args i.e. `find(sub { upToDateFiles(\%times, @_) }, "/dir/here");`.